# RangeValidator not working as expected

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a textbox in which accepts an amount due as a string. I have applied a rangevalidator to that text box so that the user doesn't enter anything over 1000.00.

Below is my RangeValidator:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rngPaymentAmount" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtPaymentAmount" MaximumValue="1000.00" MinimumValue="5.00" 
    Type="Double" CssClass="floatLeft" SetFocusOnError="True"  Display="Dynamic" meta:resourcekey="revPaymentAmountACHResource1" />
```

When clicking the submit button to make the payment I am receiving the error message when I enter in the amount 711.58

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it also fail on whole numbers (like just 711) ?

Comment: But `711.57` is allowed?

Comment: It fails on both amounts. 711.57 is allowed as its in between the max value of 5.00 - 1000.00

Comment: You say that 711 and 711.58 fails but not 711.57? I mean, in what range does the validator validate to `true` and in which to `false`? What do you use as decimal separator in your current culture?

Comment: It should validate any values between 5.00 - 1000.00.

Comment: I know what it should but what does it?

Comment: It doesn't validate against anything.

Comment: It sounds suspiciously like it's validating it as a string, in which case 711 > 1000 and 711 > 5 (because 7 comes later in the collation.)  As a test, does 6 fail and does 4 pass?

Comment: Both fail  (4 and 6)

Comment: You might want to double-check your ControlToValidate property, and make sure it's pointing at the right control.  If it's failing no matter what you enter, maybe it's validating the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0):

Just Try Out using this :

< asp:RangeValidator ID="rngPaymentAmount" runat="server" 
 ControlToValidate="TextBox2" MaximumValue="1000.00" MinimumValue="5.00" 
 Type="Double" SetFocusOnError="True"  Display="Dynamic"     meta:resourcekey="revPaymentAmountACHResource1" ErrorMessage="Values Should Be Between 5 and 1000" >
< /asp:RangeValidator>

It works fine for me!! Does not give any errors for values between 5.00 to 1000.00.
Good Luck!!!